# Rails App on Heroku Can't Connect to RDS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, amazon-rds

I'm trying to get a Rails app that's hosted on Heroku, and currently using Heroku-Postges, to instead use an instance of AWS/RDS as its datastore. The problem is that the rails app doesn't seem able get a connection and it just hangs every time it would talk to the DB.

I gather from reading a few articles about this that the way to point Heroku to it's DB is with a `DATABASE_URL` param in the form `postgres://[dbuser]:[dbpass]@[subhost].amazonaws.com:5432/[dbname]`.

Is that how it works? I'm confused about how it overrides the `database.yml` values.

I've also tried following instructions having to do with downloading a certificate and storing it in the `config/ca` folder and then appending `?sslca=config/ca/rds-ssl-ca-cert.pem&sslmode=require&encrypt=true`.

I'm able to connect directly to the RDS instance using PGAdmin, so I know it's up, running and accessible.

Is there any other way I can get visibility into what's going on here?

Comment: Make sure you check out your RDS whitelist if you're using IP whitelisting. Also: run the `heroku logs` command in your terminal to see what logs Heroku is outputting, and paste those in your question above. This will give us some more insight we need to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to fiddle with your `database.yml` values on Heroku.

But I assume you've already seen this tutorial on Heroku: [Authorizing to RDS](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon-rds#authorizing-access-to-rds-instance); you'll need to set up the security groups for the RDS to accept incoming traffic from -all- IPs.

After opening it up to all IPs, you should also limit the RDS to accept only SSL as the article suggests.

More information for each RDS type (Mysql, Postgres e.g.) can be found at the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html).

Comment: So you think maybe it's blocking the heroku IP by default, but letting in my ISPs?

Comment: How are you connecting into RDS (from your machine)? Via a bastion?

Comment: You were right, it was the AWS filtering the IP somehow. I still don't understand why it's fine with me connecting from my random home IP. It's also pretty unintuitive to me how you have to go into the EC2 section of AWS to eventually adjust settings for your RDS instance. Plus that part is kinda glossed-over in the heroku article. But once I changed that, it worked like a charm.

Comment: Its actually the security groups section, which...kinda is like the access control layer of AWS. Every single service is kinda affected by it, except for a few ...newer ones. You'll find it nifty after awhile :P

Comment: @pseudopeach i noticed the same, and its because when you create a new RDS database via the wizard, it will automatic create a security group where your current IP is whitelisted.